# How to set appTitle depending on page user taps into?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The home page has a view of a floor plan, and each room 'displays' different work (see attached image)[image: HomePage]

The gallery name {salmonComplex} shows as a header when the app opens but when the user tapes into one of the rooms I want the room name to replace or appear underneath {salmonComplex}

I created a class `MainPageHeading` and a `List<String>` to generate the heading, with an int `mainPageNumber` so i could generate the heading (i borrowed the idea from one of the quiz apps i built from a recent course).

Here is the thing

Is there a way to show the different room names without having to replicate the whole class
eg use all the code inside a new class name, say originalExhibitionHeading.

I mean that is long winded but is there a way to use List and parcel of the bits i need.

Right now it looks in the list through MainPageHeading[]. That locks the page heading.
Is there a better way to parcel of the room heading depending on which room the user enters.

any thoughts would save me time.

thnks

```
    class MainPageHeading extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MainPageHeadingState createState() => _MainPageHeadingState();
    }

    class _MainPageHeadingState extends State<MainPageHeading> {
    List<String> mainPageHeading = [
    '{ theSalmon', //0 mainloading page heading
    'Complex', //1
    ' }' //2
    ];

    int mainPageNumber = 0;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
      child: RichText(
       text: TextSpan(
        text: mainPageHeading[0],
         style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[700],
            fontFamily: 'saturn',
            fontSize: 25.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
              text: mainPageHeading[1],
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                fontFamily: 'saturn',
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              )),
          TextSpan(
              text: mainPageHeading[2],
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[700],
                fontFamily: 'saturn',
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
             ]),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           ),
          );
          }
         }



           [homePage][1]
```

[image: emulator img]

```
    void main() {
    runApp(AppState());
    }

    class AppState extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _AppStateState createState() => _AppStateState();
    }

    class _AppStateState extends State<AppState> {
    var titleText = "FirstTitle";

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Titolo",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TitleWidget(),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("Change title"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                titleText = "Other Title";
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      );
     }
     }

     class TitleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
     final titleText;

     TitleWidget({this.titleText});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Text(titleText);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure which text you want to change. Do you want to replace the Title in your AppBar with something else?

Comment: yes. the header says salmon compex atm. if the user taps on one of the room icons, say zoom or original exhibition, then when they enter that room, i want the Title salmonComplex to fall away and the name zoom or original exhibition to fill the header place.   right now i will have to generate a seperate class for each room.  is there a way to maintain the main code that creates the header but only the words to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up some sample Code for you to show how to do stuff like this.

```
void main() {
  runApp(AppState());
}

class AppState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppStateState createState() => _AppStateState();
}

class _AppStateState extends State<AppState> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Titolo",
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> mainPageHeading = [
    '{ theSalmon', //0 mainloading page heading
    'Complex', //1
    ' }' //2
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TitleWidget(
          mainPageHeading: mainPageHeading,
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text("Change title"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              mainPageHeading = ["The", "Other", "Title"];
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TitleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> mainPageHeading;

  TitleWidget({@required this.mainPageHeading});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: mainPageHeading[0],
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[700],
                fontFamily: 'saturn',
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: mainPageHeading[1],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                    fontFamily: 'saturn',
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  )),
              TextSpan(
                  text: mainPageHeading[2],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontFamily: 'saturn',
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  )),
            ]),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The AppBars title gets set from the variable `titleText`. I have a `FlatButton` with a function that changes `titleText` to different text. Note that I change that variable in a `setState` block. setState makes flutter reload your UI, updating anything that has changed. So when I click the button, the variable gets updated, and UI reloads to show the new title.

You can of course pass more variables to the `TitleWidget`.

So when you click one of your sections, put a setState in there, and update whatever variables you need to control the title.

I hope that makes sense, if you need more help, feel free to ask. Good luck!

EDIT:
Apologies, I tested the Code with a different screen setup, that caused some of your issues.
I moved the `HomeScreen` Code into a seperate widget. This is good practice and required if you want to call `setState` (like we do). The reason you were getting the red bar was because you never passed titleText to the Widget, so it tried to get a String that didn't exist, and threw an error.

Also make sure to keep an eye on your output window when something goes wrong, usually it will give you helpful error messages (scroll to the top of the error log, the top is the most important part).

Comment: Thanks so much for that.  Just starting to work out how to integrate your code.....will update as i go but i think i understand how it works....

Comment: @carpsicor Great! Feel free to comment again if you need more guidance. Also, feel free to accept the answer if you think you got it .

Comment: Hi Benedift, running into a little problem. I built a standalone app to work out your code but the title bar appears as read but the rest of the app renders as it should. Looking at what you posted it seems to me(inexperienced) that the first part of the stateful widget seems missig so I added the front end code which ran the app but left the appTitle area red....wht am i doing wrong?

Comment: @carpsicor Hi. I only posted the State, so you were right that the actual Stateful Widget needed to be added. I am at work right now, post the code you have now and maybe a Pic of your emulator. I ll have a look when I m done with work.

Comment: just uploaded code and an image. I think i have not explained myself tho....I have added quite a lot of TextStyle to my titles. I need to maintain that text style but change the words on a page. It's like i need a variable that recognises that i have entered a room of the exhibition and then passes a variable that places the words into the Textstyle and then up to the page. does that make sense? no probs if not for you....thanks for taking the time :D

Comment: @carpsicor Alright I updated the answer with full code and some explenation at the bottom. Hope it all works now!

Comment: @carpsicor  I also took the liberty to implement your RichText Widget really quick. Let me know if you have questions about how it works.

Comment: about to start working on it so will get back to you ASAP.  Thank you so much for all your help. appreciated.

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you so much for your help. Will read through and make sense of the code and borrow it for other areas of the project...know anything about transform.translate. next big layout issue I need to resolve....about to post to stackflow

Comment: @carpsicor I m glad it worked! No problem at all. I ll have a look at your new question when I m done with work. Good luck!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087859/set-a-drawer-to-portrait-even-if-image-goes-to-landscape