# Set a Drawer to portrait even if image goes to landscape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using this template to build out an App. First attempt at App building but want to use this for an online exhibition platform for my paintings and photography etc. This is from a Google Flutter demo on Youtube.

https://github.com/MarcinusX/drawer_challenge/blob/master/lib/main.dart

When you run the app in custom guitar drawer mode(set the flip Bool to true ) the Drawer is set to the left side of the screen(portrait mode).  I want to use the length of the screen for info and other menu items for the App.

however i need to display the images and paintings in landscape mode.

## this is the issue.  Is there a way to leave the Drawer as it would be in portrait mode?

ie when the user turns the device to landscape mode, then the Drawer will turn up from the bottom of the screen, and not the left side of the screen as it currently does?

or is there a way to set an image into landscape mode through ratio change that could be done without orientating the device to landscape?

I tried transform.rotate on the image but that means it get renders in portrait mode in landscape orientation.  I also tried playing with the Transform.translate but can't work out how to set the Sizebox differently

I am new to this and wish to use the lockdown time to have a place for my work of the last 15 years so can work out how to code the images and place the controls and audio player for the App but if i can get the basic structure set then i can get going with the design.

any help would be great but if need be I will have to design the App around this
....
[app in portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6ZjX.jpg)

[app in landscape mode, want drawer to turn in from bottom of screen not left edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5NpM.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe provide some images of how you want it to behave? I can't really visualize it from your post.

Comment: hello, just added images. hope that helps explain things.  I want the drawer to remain as it would in portrait mode even though the image will be displayed in landscape mode.  if that makes sense